# Call controller with tag helpers including data from search bar in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i'm a bit new to front-end so please be patient.

I trying to create a form with asp.net core 2.2 MVC, for the call everybody online suggest to use ajax, but i would like to use the new tag helpers.
This is my code (the controller ***user*** is a different controller that the one i am in)

```
       <form method="get" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="UserByUsername">
           <input id="userName" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="1">
           <button type="submit" value="userName">a</button>
       </form>
```

The button call the same url with ?1=value

But i would like to call the controller and the action specified in the tag, with the param as part of the string user/userbyusername/**whatusertype**

What should i change to make it work? thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** ----------------------

with asp-route-value i am passing the parameter, but it pass "userName" and not the value of the texboxid "userName" right below

```
   <form method="get"asp-route-username="userName" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="UserByUsername">
        <input id="userName" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        <button type="submit" value="userName">a</button>
    </form>
```

How can i pass that value?

Comment: Please use asp-route-id to pass the parameters

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! but how can i pass the value from the input to the tag? i used the id of the input but is not passing it.

Comment: i put asp-route-username="userName", (same as id) but is not passing the value of the textbox

Comment: You have to handle this in the route config

Comment: Yes i have done that, but i can't pass the value of the input to asp-route-value

Comment: Kindly refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186996/discussion-between-ratheesh-and-neos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write your `form` as exactly as follows:

```
<form method="post" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="UserByUserName">
        <input name="userName" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now in your controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UserByUserName(string userName)
{
    // do whatever you want to do with `userName`

    return View();
}
```

Here I have used `post` method. You can also use `get` method as you shown in your code. For this just replace `method="post"` with `method="get"` and `[HttpPost]` with `[HttpGet]`.

Everything should work fine now.